# PHP - check if file is finished encoding

Tags: php, uploadify

I have a .bat file that encodes an mp3 file on the server side, and I also have a php function that checks if the file exists, and then adds it as an HTML list item.  The problem I'm running into - sometimes the mp3 file isn't done encoding on the server side.  If somebody were to try downloading the file while it's in the process of encoding it will crash the browser.

Can I check to make sure the filesize is finished increasing before listing the item?

Here's the function that checks if the file exists:

```
function ListDir($dir_handle,$path) {
    global $listing;
    echo "<ul>";
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
      $dir =$path . $file;
      if(is_dir($dir) && $file != '.' && $file !='..' && filesize($file) {
            $handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open file $file");
            echo "<li>".$dir;
            ListDir($handle, $dir);
            echo "</li>";
      } elseif($file != '.' && $file !='..' && $file !='.htaccess') {
          $new_string = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z.]", "", $file);
            echo '<li><a href="'. str_replace('wav', 'mp3', $dir) .'">'.str_replace('wav', 'mp3',  $new_string).'</a></li>';
      }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    closedir($dir_handle);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the bat encode, then move to a final location for a "finished" state, if it doesn't exist there - it's not done. This is similar to drew010's answer except it utilizes the same file, from a working directory to a production directory.

This also prevents it being accessible by any resources until it's ready which could potentially cause problems.

Comment: Thanks!  That got me about 90% of the way there.  There's still a slight delay while the file is copying from the temp directory to the final directory.  I guess I'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really know the final filesize, so have your bat file create a file like mp3filename.work or something and then have the bat file delete it when the encoding finishes, so if the .work file doesn't exist, then the encoding is done.

Comment: I'm actually keeping the source file in an archive.

Comment: Before you start encoding the file, create a temp file that you can use to indicate the file is not done encoding, after the encoding program finishes, have the bat file remove the temp file.  If the temp file is not there, then its done encoding.  I don't think it matters the source file is in an archive.  Maybe post your bat file code.